# Why does Ronald Ruth integrate momentum as velocity in his 1983 paper "A canonical integration technique"?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, computational-physics, integration

I am trying to apply a time integration technique for a system of discrete particles using Hamiltonian symplectic mechanics.

In his relatively well-known [paper](https://doi.org/10.1109/TNS.1983.4332919) ([CERN](http://cds.cern.ch/record/143981?ln=en),[PDF](https://accelconf.web.cern.ch/p83/PDF/PAC1983_2669.PDF)) on symplectic integrators, Ruth gives a few integration methods of various order's accuracy.  They all apply the rule for the coordinates that
$$x = x_i + p t$$ or some variant of that where momentum is integrated directly as a velocity.  I notice that his kinetic energy term is actually one mass unit too many with $p^2/2$ but this should compound the problem rather than balance it out.

Is there some implicit assumption about unit mass here? When implementing these higher order methods in my own code I would just do the usual $$x=x_i +tp/m.$$ Is that still correct?

Comment: Likely just setting $m=1$ so that they didn't have to carry around a parameter they didn't need in the equations.

Comment: This question is similar to [Peskin and Schroeder, where is the mass in the denominator of the simple harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/605535/145491). It is just notation, but it might be worth an answer explaining how operators can be redefined to make equations simple but their interpretation confusing for novice readers. For example, I was certainly confused the first time I saw the harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian written as $H=P^2+X^2$, not realizing that the author was using $X=\sqrt{m/2}\omega x$ and $P=p/\sqrt{2m}$.

Comment: yes but $x = x + pt$ strikes me as the undiscerning error of a undergrad student rather than the brilliant work of a particle physicist. I'd have thought the distinction between Hamiltonian and Lagrangian mechanics were to be emphasized not blurred.

Comment: Only slightly paraphrasing [Humpty-Dumpty](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Through_the_Looking-Glass#Chapter_6:_Humpty_Dumpty) “When a theorist uses a symbol, it means what they choose it to mean – neither more nor less.”   I certainly don't disagree with your irritation. I have felt it many times myself when trying to figure out a paper's notation.

Comment: Yes it certainly doesn’t make a difference to the paper‘s purpose but it does feel like an abuse of something. Perhaps one could show that such a momentum variable could be a Legendre transform of the velocity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Andrew states in a comment, the author is simply setting $m=1$ to avoid excess notational clutter.

> yes but $x=x+pt$ strikes me as the undiscerning error of a undergrad student rather than the brilliant work of a particle physicist.

A more advanced physicist tends to be aware of when a particular symbol is crucial to the context in which it appears and when it is not. In this case, the presence of $m$ is irrelevant to the algorithm; if you wish to include it, it can be easily replaced via dimensional analysis.

---

Alternatively, note that the equations of motion for a particle with Hamiltonian $H:= p^2/2m + V(x,t)$ are
$$\matrix{\dot x = p/m \\\dot p = -\partial V/\partial x}$$
If we define a new time variable $\tau \equiv t/m$ and a scaled potential $\tilde V \equiv m V$ and denote differentiation with respect to $\tau$ with a prime rather than a dot, the equations of motion become
$$\matrix{x' = p\\ p' = -\partial \tilde V / \partial x}$$

Once we've used the algorithm to obtain $x(\tau)$, we have all of the information we need to reconstruct the trajectory as a function of $t$ (e.g. the position at time $t$ is $x(t/m)$).

---

While it may not appear this way to you at the moment, extensive experience with dimensional analysis makes the equivalence between these approaches about as trivial as the equivalence between $6/8$ and $3/4$. The presence of $m$ is irrelevant for understanding how the algorithm works, so it can be omitted without fear of ambiguity; though it may be not so obvious, it can be replaced with no difficulty either by dimensional analysis (replace $pt$ with $pt/m$ while writing your code) or by implicitly scaling the variables.

Comment: thanks. I guess this works for multiple particle masses too except we would be differentiating with different time scales so could be tricky to get interactions right

Comment: @Notachance Multiple particle masses would be problematic because dimensional analysis could not distinguish between them, so in that case you could set at most one mass equal to $1$. You'd need to also include the relative mass $m/M$ of the other in the Hamiltonian/equations of motion.